# Is there a way to check if specific hardware is supported under the kernel?

Tags: kernel, hardware

I'm planning on building my first PC and I've decided on an ASRock z77 extreme4 motherboard. I've searched on google, but I haven't had any luck finding whether it's supported. **Is there a new list of supported hardware?** (I haven't been able to find any recent ones(about the 12.04).)

I also, checked to find the chips used on it (I read on a forums post that I should and then check if those chips are supposrted), for instance it has a Broadcom BCM57781 ethernet chip, but again through google I haven't been able to find anything on that. Is there a site to check for such things? What do you suggest I do? I've searched about anything I can think of but found no answers. Any help much appreciated.

(P.S.I tried to make the question as generic as possible-check about hardware, not check about my specific motherboard)

Answer (score 1):

There is the website http://linuxhcl.com hardware compatibility list, and if you search for "linux hcl" you will find other sites that keep other lists. The information on these sites isn't always the most up to date, but they are supported by the community. Don't forget to submit the information of your hardware and help make them better.